# Regroup json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, format

I have this json

```
[
  {
    "id": "03868185",
    "month_10": 6,
  },
  {
    "id": "03870584",
    "month_6": 2,
  },
  {
    "id": "03870584",
    "month_7": 5,
  },
  {
    "id": "51295",
    "month_1": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": "51295",
    "month_10": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": "55468",
    "month_11": 1,
  }
]
```

and I would like to retrieve this format :

```
[
  {
    "id": "03868185",
    "month_10": 6,
  },
  {
    "id": "03870584",
    "month_6": 2,
    "month_7": 5,
  },
  {
    "id": "51295",
    "month_1": 1,
    "month_10": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": "55468",
    "month_11": 1,
  }
]
```

How to process it with javascript?

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: JavaScript has nothing built in to do it, so you need to loop over it and process it.

Comment: If you say "You would like to retrieve it that way", you simply have to ask the guy providing you with the JSON to restructure it. However you could also restructure it yourself. Just look through the array, get the id, check if that id is already present in your target array items, if yes, only add the value, otherwise add the whole item. Voila.

Comment: As @epascarello suggests and then add your best attempt to the question if it still does not "group" by id (or whatever might be the concept behind the wanted "format"). I'm sure people will help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.

```
var array = [
{
"id": "03868185",
"month_10": 6,
},
{
"id": "03870584",
"month_6": 2,
},
{
"id": "03870584",
"month_7": 5,
},
{
"id": "51295",
"month_1": 1,
},
{
"id": "51295",
"month_10": 1,
},
{
"id": "55468",
"month_11": 1,
}
]

var resultArray = array.filter(function(item) {
var ref = this[item.id];
if(!ref) {
 return (this[item.id] = item);
}
else
{
 var keys = Object.keys(item);
 ref[keys[1]] = item[keys[1]];
}
}, {});

console.log(resultArray);
```

plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/7onuPTte0Akd4ulbN8Hz?p=preview

Comment: It works like a charm thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use some [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and a hash table as reference.

```js
var data = [{ "id": "03868185", "month_10": 6, }, { "id": "03870584", "month_6": 2, }, { "id": "03870584", "month_7": 5, }, { "id": "51295", "month_1": 1, }, { "id": "51295", "month_10": 1, }, { "id": "55468", "month_11": 1, }],
    grouped = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.id]) {
        this[a.id] = {};
        grouped.push(this[a.id]);
    }
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
        this[a.id][k] = a[k];
    }, this);
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```